# How to calculate the percentage for a dataset by using groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I am the new beginner of using Python and I have some questions about how to use python to calculate the percentage for the certain of the columns by using groupby function. 
I would be grateful if you could help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks a lot!!!

I already tried the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd     
import numpy as np    
from itertools import groupby    

#dataset = pd.read_excel('ABC.xlsx')    
casual = dataset[['Location', 'Fruit_Types']].dropna()    
casual_group = casual.groupby(['Location', 'Fruit_Types'], sort = False).count().reset_index()    
casual_matrix = casual_group.pivot(index = 'Location', columns = 'Fruit_Types').fillna(0)
```

**I have an excel data-file like as below:**
[image: excel data-file]

**And my expected output like this:**
[image: expected output]

Comment: can you please provide the original input as a text so that we can copy/paste it in to our IDE's?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
map_key = dataset.groupby(['Fruit_Types']).size().to_dict()

df = dataset.dropna().groupby(['Fruit_Types', 'Location']).size()
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Count'})
df['Total'] = df['Fruit_Types'].map(map_key)
df['Percentage'] = df.Count / df.Total
df = df.set_index(['Fruit_Types', 'Location'])
print(df)
```

```
                         Count  Total  Percentage
Fruit_Types Location                             
Apple       Japan            1      4    0.250000
            USA              3      4    0.750000
Bannana     Costa Rica       1      3    0.333333
            Philippines      1      3    0.333333
            USA              1      3    0.333333
Mango       Ecuador          2      3    0.666667
            Philippines      1      3    0.333333
Strawberry  Japan            2      5    0.400000
            Korea            3      5    0.600000
```